# MySQL MBRContains statement throwing MySQLExceptionError

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc, spatial-query

I am working on a Java project, where we use its sql library functions to access and query from MySQL server.

The code that raises the problem is:

```
String setBox = "SET @box = 
                                'Polygon((" + lx + " " + ry + ","
                                            + rx + " " + ry + ","
                                            + lx + " " + ly + ","
                                            + rx + " " + ly + ","
                                            + lx + " " + ry + "))';\n";

ResultSet regionResult = stmt.executeQuery(setBox + 
  "SELECT ItemID FROM ItemPoint WHERE MBRContains(GeomFromText(@box), Coords);\n");
```

The error occurs in on the second statement (ResultSet regionResult  = ...)

The error I receive is:

"com.mysql.jdbc.exception.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to user near 'SELECT ItemID FROM ItemPoint WHERE MBRContains((GeomFromText(@box), Coords)' at line 2"

I am not sure why there is a syntax error as I am basing it off: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/using-spatial-indexes.html.

My MySQL server version is: 5.5.40-0ubuntu0.14.04.1 (Ubuntu)

Comment: How is this object defined: `Polygon` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to make it work by doing this instead:

```
String box = "Polygon((" 
                        + lx + " " + ry + ", "
                        + rx + " " + ry + ", "
                        + rx + " " + ly + ", "
                        + lx + " " + ly + ", "
                        + lx + " " + ry + "))";

ResultSet regionResult = stmt.executeQuery(//setBox + 
  "SELECT ItemID FROM ItemPoint WHERE MBRContains(GeomFromText(' " + box +  " '), Coords);\n");
```

Answer (score 1):

You problem is not MySql is the `PreparedStatement`. You cant use it to run two statements like that you have to use a `CallableStatement`

For your problem it will be something like:

```
String callString = "{ call SET @box = 'Polygon(( ? ?,
                                       ? ?,
                                       ? ?,
                                       ? ?,
                                       ? ?))'; 
                      SELECT ItemID 
                        FROM ItemPoint 
                       WHERE MBRContains(GeomFromText(@box), Coords); }";

CallableStatement callableStatement = con.prepareCall(callString);
callableStatement.setInt(1, lx);
callableStatement.setInt(2, ry);
callableStatement.setInt(3, rx);
callableStatement.setInt(4, ry);
callableStatement.setInt(5, lx);
callableStatement.setInt(6, ly);
callableStatement.setInt(7, rx);
callableStatement.setInt(8, ly);
callableStatement.setInt(9, lx);
callableStatement.setInt(10, ry);
ResultSet regionResult = callableStatement.executeQuery();
```

Note that this may not work the way it is. You may need to change something, this is the basic idea. I'm doing this from memory, so...

Comment: This method has now moved the syntax error to the first line 'SET @box  = ...'.